# OpenIdConnectProtocolInvalidNonceException. Can the user still be authenticated on AuthenticationFailed notification?

Tags: c#, asp.net, owin, openid-connect, openid

Is there any case in which user can have an expired nonce exception `OpenIdConnectProtocolInvalidNonceException` and still be authenticated?

I have found an old implementation in my company's source code where a previous developer implemented the following on `AuthenticationFailed` notification:

```
Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
{
        AuthenticationFailed = n =>
            {
               if(n.Exception is OpenIdConnectProtocolInvalidNonceException)
                  {    
                     // This is the confusing line
                     if(n.OwinContext.Authentication.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                         {
                             n.SkipToNextMiddleware();
                             return Task.FromResult(0);
                          }
                  }
             }
     }
```

As you see, the `if` statement `if(n.OwinContext.Authentication.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)` caused me some confusion since we are actually on AuthenticationFailed notification.

While debugging with the expired nonce exception, I always get `n.OwinContext.Authentication.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated = false`.

Is this `if` statement useless?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending some time on this topic, I have found that the case in which user can be already authenticated but getting a `OpenIdConnectProtocolInvalidNonceException`, is when user clicks back button in the browser after having successfully logged in. In this case, the user is authenticated but the nonce is missing.